# Elegant way to get values in nested dictionaries for a specific key?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a nested dictionary in Python. I can access the `A` element like this:

```
D[0]['detLog'][n]['A']
```

where n is from 0 to the length of the `detLog`... In Matlab I could use something like this:

```
D[0]['detLog'][:]['A']
```

`:` meaning "for all elements".

Is there something similar in Python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
[d['A'] for d in D[0]['detLog']]
```

For scientific computing with Python, you may also want to look into [NumPy](https://numpy.org/) and [SciPy](https://scipy.org/), specifically the [NumPy for Matlab users](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html) documentation.

Comment: WOW, this is it. Thanks for the reply, and for sharing the "name" of the solution along the doc.  great.

Comment: I can't believe it... it's getting even better :-D

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this, though it isn't so pretty:

```
[x['A'] for x in D[0]['detLog'].itervalues() if 'A' in x]
```

What we're doing is extracting the 'A' value from each dict if it exists, otherwise adding nothing to the result.